# Showing data that is not already in the data base

Tags: mysql, select, query, mysql-8.0

I have the following problem. I want to search a query in an existing data base and that the result shows me the entries of the query that are NOT already in the database.

Minimal example:

```
| ID | name | 
| 1 | Paul | 
| 2 | Clara |
```

ID Query (1,3)

The result should be 3!

So I want to do something like this:

```
Select * from names Where ID Not in (1,3);
```

But well this is obviously not correct.

Furthermore, I don't want to insert an additional table with the query!
Does anyone know a solution for this problem?

Comment: Specify DBMS and its version. In common - your data must be a table, not a CSV list.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT args_list.id
FROM ( SELECT 1 id 
       UNION ALL
       SELECT 3 ) args_list /* the ID's you need to check for presence */
LEFT JOIN names ON args_list.id = names.id
WHERE names.id IS NULL
```

In MySQL 8+ you can transfer the id's list into the query as CSV string and parse it to separate values in CTE. It will be something like (not tested)

```
WITH src AS ( SELECT '1,3' src ),
     RECURSIVE 
     num AS ( SELECT 1 num
              UNION ALL
              SELECT num + 1
              FROM num
              WHERE num < (SELECT MAX(LENGTH(src) - LENGTH(REPLACE(src, ',', ''))
                           FROM src) ),
     ids AS ( SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(src, ',', num), ',', -1)
              FROM src, num )
SELECT ids.id
FROM ids
LEFT JOIN names ON ids.id = names.id
WHERE names.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

If your list is small you can use this syntax:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    (SELECT 1 Id
     UNION ALL 
     SELECT 2
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 3
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 4
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 5) val
WHERE
    Id NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM tbl);
```

> ```
> | Id |
> | -: |
> |  2 |
> |  4 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8ff6c5d85ad4f34ac4304670012470c5)*